# Unsaved work warning fails in safari

Tags: javascript, html, browser, safari

I need to warn app users that accidentally close that they have unsaved work. My research shows different browsers act differently; alas through this link:
http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/exit_confirmation.php
I got code that works in:
IE11, Chrome45, firefox40, opera31.. and fails on safari 5.1.7 (under windows 8).

The test code html and js :

```
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>Unsaved Work Warning</title>
</head>

 <body >
        <h1>Try to close page and get confirm warning
<script language="javascript">
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling    process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;

</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like I need to stick in code to detect nav-out (including tab and browser closure) and issue "unsaved work" warning for safari.

Safari experts please advise.

Comment: Your code is dependent on support for *window.event*, consider setting the listener using *addEventListener* instead. Or use `window.onload = function(){goodbye(event)};`

Comment: I am looking for a safari specific event that fires upon closure. If you have a  verified code that traps this, prey tell! As for trying this that and the other, I've tried every piece of code on the subject I could find, conjure or guess. And here I am, one safari short of the full pack.